# WebApi Service wanting CSRF cookie, but shouldn't?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api, csrf

I have a WebApi service that has been working for a long time now, but suddenly, it's responding with **The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present**

This service has never required this before, and the only thing changed since it was working is a new "HttpPost" function was added to the controller and several were deleted. Things I have tried:

- In my startup.cs I have:

  ```
  app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
  ```
- Commenting out that line, but no change.
- Deleting all references to CORS DLLs in the project, theoretically making it impossible to throw this error?
- Decorating my methods with [DisableCors] didn't work, it wasn't recognized.
- Rebooting the server
- Nothing in the IIS settings seems to affect this.
- There is nothing about CORS in the web.config of the calling service, or the error'd one. There's no "requireSSL" or anything like that, just a connection string and some system libraries.

This is a local service being called from the local machine, running in the full version of IIS 7.5. No other errors are reported, and similar services hosted in the same way are not throwing this error.

I am not interested in how to post the cookie from the request, I need to turn off whatever is causing the receiving service from wanting this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the API from an MVC project give this a try. It tells the API to not look for the cookie and instead use the name from a passed in claim through a token. You do not need to pass in a token (although you should) this is just telling the API not to look for the cookie.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

    //let mvc know you are using a token and not a cookie like it expects
    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was this never should have been a cross-site request in the first place. I wasn't clear about that in the question, but these services are all running on the same domain as the caller. So, that should have been my first clue - *this isn't a cross-site request, but the service thought it was*. That lead me to check the IIS settings in the App pool, and lo and behold, that one service was pointed at the wrong site! It was in the right app pool, but it was living in a different site. Fixing it to run in the same site as the caller makes it not a cross-site request, and this error doesn't happen, and it doesn't require any tokens or cookies or any of that.